# How can I make Keepass auto-type make hostname-aware?

Tags: passwords, password-management

How can I trigger the [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) auto-type function by hostname and not by window title only and thus make it more accurate and secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Hostname in Title bar Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9231) to add the actual hostname to the title bar and match against it.